# Realm android: Cant migrate primarykey from 0.82.2 to 0.86.0 because of field supporting null

Tags: android, migration, realm

I have a table with a primary key in 0.82.2 android app with following field:

```
// Each uid is generated using UUID strings:
@PrimaryKey
private String uid;
```

Today I have updated to Realm 0.86.0 to get the new migration api (as I added another table and wanted to migrate existing users data).

However, it seems that the existing data from 0.82.2 realm file allowed the primarykey uid to be nullable (realm tells me this when I run app without any migration for the uid field.

So, I tried to create a new primary key field called 'id' and then migrate the non null values overs using the following code:

```
dogSchema.removePrimaryKey();
dogSchema.addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY) 
                    .transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
                        @Override
                        public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {

                            String oldUid = obj.getString("uid");

                            // Bring over any non null uids, generate new id to replace nulls
                            if (oldUid == null || oldUid.equals("")) {

                                // Null, so generate one as primarykey doesnt allow nulls:
                                String newUid = RealmUtils.generateUID();
                                Log.d(TAG, "### New filler dog uid = " + newUid);
                                obj.setString("id", newUid);
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "### Old dog uid = " + oldUid);
                                obj.setString("id", oldUid);

                            }
                        }
                    });

            dogSchema.removeField("uid");
```

However, after the migration runs, Realm throws exception stating: Field 'id' cant be a primaryKey as existing realm file already contains duplicate data. Even though I can see each ID value is different.

If I change the addfield line for id to be without the PrimaryKey attribute (see below), I get further, but hit another exception saying id cant be primary key, presumably because my Model has @PrimaryKey annotation.

```
dogSchema.addField("id", String.class)
```

How can I migrate the primary key over to Realm 0.86.0?

Comment: How does your your Java RealmObject class look like before and after the migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Christian Melchior's help over on the Realm java github issues page (https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1902), I managed to migrate the old schema primarykey over to realm 0.86.0:

The end code was (note the lack of 'setNullable()' call)

"If your current uid field might contain null values you should be able to do it like this (without needing an additional field):"

```
  dogSchema.transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
        @Override
        public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
            String oldUid = obj.getString("uid");
            // Bring over any non null uids, generate new id to replace nulls
            if (oldUid == null || oldUid.equals("")) {
                // Null, so generate one as primarykey doesnt allow nulls:
                String newUid = RealmUtils.generateUID();
                Log.d(TAG, "### New filler dog uid = " + newUid);
                obj.setString("uid", newUid);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "### Old dog uid = " + oldUid);
                obj.setString("uid", oldUid);
            }
        }
    });
```